# STM32L4 clock set up

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, clock, pll, st

I'm using STM32L4R5 for my project and this is my first time designing a clock source and using an ST microcontroller.
I'm trying to figure out the clocking hardware configuration by reading the clock tree.
I'm planning to use the HSE by adding a crystal.

So for example, if I add a 4MHz crystal at HSE, how do I make the output to Cortex system to 120MHz?
What I understand from the Clock Tree is the HSE signal can be routed to PLL and we can use the Boost mode to boost to 120MHz, but at the output of the SYSCLK, there's a "AHB PRESC", what is "AHB PRESC" and what's the function? And there's a "/8" as well before the Cortex system timer, does it mean my frequency will get divided by 8?

Thank you.

Datasheet - https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l4r5vi.pdf
[image]

Comment: Do you have STM32CubeMX? It has a graphical clock configuration tool and will generate the configuration code for you. After that you can inspect the code line by line to understand exactly what it is doing (or just use it as is).

Comment: AHB PRESC is a clock divider. If it is set to 1 then HCLK = SYSCLK. If it is set to 2 then HCLK = SYSCLK / 2, etc. I don't see any clock multipliers. I think the fastest you can go is 48 MHz and you will need a 48 MHz crystal to do it. But I could be wrong.

Comment: The [STM32L4+ Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00310109-stm32l4-series-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) has much more details than the datasheet and some of the answers you're looking for.  The [STM32CubeL4](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubel4.html) software package has many examples.  And STM32CubeMX/IDE have already been mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with other comments already provided, simply use CubeMX to generate proper clocks. It is built into CubeIDE which you can use to develop code and debug it.

So with CubeMX, set RCC to use HSE with crystal, then in the clock configurarion, set external crystal to be 4 MHz, select HSE as PLL source, and select PLLCLK as system clock. Adjust PLL input divider M to 1 and multiplier N to 60 and postdivider R to 2.

Yes the system tick timer (generally) runs as sysclk/8, but that is just a timer, the CPU clock is still 120 MHz.

Comment: How do I set my CPU clock to 120MHz? I'm assuming CPU clock is the main frequency that's running the microcontroller?

Comment: I just described the procedure in my answer. Sysclk is the clock that runs the CPU core, there is no other CPU clock. The whole MCU does not run on a single clock, there's like 30 other clocks as well that run the whole MCU and various peripherals.